# Enable disabled Radiobuttonlist with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a radiobuttonlist initially disabled (Enabled="false"). I want to enable it on a button click.
The jQuery line that would enable the radiobuttonlist is as follows:

```
$("#<%=MyRadioButtonList.ClientID%>").prop("disabled", false);
```

But it does not work.  What I noticed is that ASP.NET encloses the input tag with 
 which, if I understand correctly, prevents the javascript code from enabling the list.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try like this

```
$("#<%=MyRadioButtonList.ClientID %>").find('input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is very strange. You must escape it.To escape character use '\\' in front of it.
You ca do this too:

```
$(document.getElementById('<%=MyRadioButtonList.ClientID%>')).prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: n_ilievski, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "your selector is very strange." Could you please clarify?

Comment: My point was that the selector id is containing characters like "<" and ".". Special characters that jquery detects and trys to select something else, so you can't be sure that you select the dom element correctly. But looks like you've got your answer from Dhaval Marthak. As additional helpful information: .children('input') is faster then .find('input')